# Bonitasoft external forms

Tags: url, external, bonita

First I would like if someone can point out extensive  information about connecting external forms with Bonita BPM. That would be ***very*** helpful.

Nevertheless,...

I found that for a human task to use external forms instead of the UI Designer one, I have to

> 1. Select the **Pool / Human Task**
> 2. Go to **Details** panel
> 3. Click on **Execution** tab
> 4. - If **Pool**, select **Instantiation form** pane
>    - If **Human Task**, select **Forms** pane
> 5. Select **External URL** radio button
> 6. Enter the *URL*

Now, here's my questions...

> If not local, what must be the url, because I always see Bonita appending the specified url to it's native one, rather than redirecting as it should do?
>
> I mean what is the point of giving an absolute url?

---

> If local, what should be the url?
>
> Should it be absolute `file:///C:/.../.../Desktop/.../testingform.html` or relative `testingform.html`?
>
> If relative, than where should the file or folder be placed?

---

For now this questions will be my first step in intergrating custom web app with Bonita BPM.

I hope there will be someone who has asked these same questions and found the answer and be **very** much willing to answer these again.

Answer (score 0):

Your external page should be served from the same server of Bonita (you can place the page in webapp/ROOT, for example).

The page should be able to execute a post to the task, with a json compliant the  contract.

For example, using Angular, with a contract defined with a string named 'mystring':

```
$scope.contract = { mystring: "myvalue" }
$http.post('/bonita/API/bpm/userTask/' + id + '/execution', $scope.contract);
```

The id is the path parameter passed to your external html page.

I hope this can help you.